# Does python have Matlab's `ans` variable that captures returned value not stored in any variable?

Tags: python, matlab

If you are familiar with Matlab, there is a global variable `ans` that captures the first return value of a function that is not assigned to any particular variable. Is there any matching construct in Python?

Comment: Just FYI, the `ans` variable is not global (unless you declare it to be for some reason).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You’re looking for `_`:

```
>>> 1+1
2
>>> _
2
>>> def f(x): 
...     return x+1
... 
>>> f(3)
4
>>> _
4
```

Comment: After many years, I am positively impressed with python: the symbol '_' is ugly, but highly functional.